# how to use RegEx properly

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am not good in regular expressions. I copied this once from somewhere for javascript to check if an inpu is a valid e-mail adress:

```
const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
if(re.test(state.mail)) //...
```

And it worked just fine. Now i want to adapt it for flutter.

I tried

```
RegExp re = RegExp(r'/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/');
if(re.hasMatch(mail)) //...
```

but every adress i try fails. How do i use it properly?

Comment: Please do not use random regexen to validate emails. There’s virtually no manageable regex that validates the relevant RFCs entirely. It’ll always accept some “invalid” addresses and reject valid addresses. At best, use something like `.+@.+` as a very rough validation. The real validation is always trying to send an email.

Comment: No, please don't use this regex to validate email.  It's wrong.  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the  slashes `/` at the beginning and end of the pattern. Dart does not use slashes to delimit regular expressions.

```dart
void main(){
  RegExp re = RegExp(r'^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$');
  
  print(re.hasMatch('test@gmail.com')); // --> true
  print(re.hasMatch('test')); // --> false

}
```